# What's the Java feature that lets you write into a String?

Tags: java, string

I've done this in Java before but I can't remember how exactly.

You create a String:

```
String foo = "She %s sea shells by the seashore.";
```

Then you can write into the String the word "sells".

What do you use for that?

Answer (score 10):

```
String myString = "sells";
String foo = String.format("She %s sea shells by the seashore.", myString);
```

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for the [`Formatter` class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html), or the [`String.format` convenience method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29):

```
String.format(foo, "sells");
```

Answer (score 3):

String.format?

```
Object a[] = { "Real's HowTo", "http://www.any.com" ,
        java.util.Calendar.getInstance()};

String s = String.format("Welcome %1$s at %2$s ( %3$tY %3$tm %3$te )", a);
System.out.println(s);
//  output : Welcome Real's HowTo at http://www.any.com (2010 06 26)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `String.Format` function for this.

Answer (score 1):

Straight from the source (and my bookmarks)...

```
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   // Send all output to the Appendable object sb
   Formatter formatter = new Formatter(sb, Locale.US);

   // Explicit argument indices may be used to re-order output.
   formatter.format("%4$2s %3$2s %2$2s %1$2s", "a", "b", "c", "d");
```

UPDATE: Sorry meant to include the link: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html